# Eclipse plugin support in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, plugins

Does Visual Studio Code have any support for existing Eclipse plugins?  Or, is there an extension or adaption layer that would allow Eclipse plugins to run within Visual Studio Code?

Comment: In which language are these written? VSC is a JavaScript based editor and all extensions are written in JavaScript or translated from Typescript

Comment: The plugins are written in Java and packages up as .jar files.

Comment: that will not happen, Eclipse and VSC have very different API's for extensions